# Elasticsearch indexing doc with file size 42 MB created over 2GB heap member

Tags: elasticsearch

I' trying to index a 42 MB doc, and I saw the over 2GB memory were used in the heap.

```
>> ls -l data.json
-rw-r--r--@ 1 user  Network\Domain Users  42798016 Oct 29 11:03 data.json

>> curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/my-index/my-type -d data.json
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

Below is the error fro Elasticsearch

```
2018-10-29T12:02:42,583][WARN ][o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] [Cfr4bRu] [gc][1665] overhead, spent [3.3s] collecting in the last [3.6s]
[2018-10-29T12:02:46,386][WARN ][o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] [Cfr4bRu] [gc][1666] overhead, spent [3.2s] collecting in the last [3.8s]
[2018-10-29T12:02:50,038][WARN ][o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] [Cfr4bRu] [gc][1667] overhead, spent [3.2s] collecting in the last [3.6s]
[2018-10-29T12:02:53,110][WARN ][o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] [Cfr4bRu] [gc][1668] overhead, spent [3s] collecting in the last [3s]
[2018-10-29T12:02:56,683][WARN ][o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] [Cfr4bRu] [gc][1669] overhead, spent [3.5s] collecting in the last [3.5s]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Dumping heap to java_pid93445.hprof ...
Heap dump file created [2900298449 bytes in 37.716 secs]
```

How should I fix this?

Comment: It depend of your mapping. But anyway 2GB heap size is a small value. Cant you just increase the heap size ?

Comment: What is your current heap memory setting ? 2 GB ? You can check this in jvm.options file under ES installation. Please note ES uses considerable amount of heap to run so as suggested above consider increasing heap memory to atleast 4 GB. If the issue sill occurs, analyze the heap dump and look at which object is cosuming most of the heap.